# how to get sydney time using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get sydney time using javascript and jquery.
I have retrieve UTC and then add 11 to its hours to get the sydney time as below:

```
var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(d.getUTCHours()+11);
```

but the issue is daylight savings which impacts this.
Is any workaround I need to do here?

Comment: [This](http://michaelapproved.com/articles/daylight-saving-time-dst-detect) May be helpful.

Comment: if your okay using a plugin then go for http://momentjs.com/

Comment: check this link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58728/JavaScript-code-to-determine-when-DayLight-Savings

Comment: Sydney, Australia, or Sydney, Nova Scotia?